# Is this equation formatting ok?

Tags: equations, formatting

Thanks you for your time,

I have a long equation, and I wrote English expression as follows.

```
\begin{cases}
& A = V*(cos(Phi)*sin(Psi) \\
& B = cos(Psi)*sin(Phi)*sin(The)) + U*cos(Psi)*cos(The) \\
& C = W*(cos(Psi)*sin(Phi) \\
& D = cos(Phi)*sin(Psi)*sin(The)) + U*cos(The)*sin(Psi)
\end{cases}
\newline
than, full dynamic model is \newline
\begin{cases}
 & P x= R*V - Q*W + g*sin(The) \\ 
 & Q x= P*W - R*U - g*cos(conj(The))*sin(Phi) \\ 
 & R x= Q*U - P*V + \frac{Fb}{m} - g*cos(Phi)*cos(The) \\ 
 & W*(sin(Phi)*sin(Psi) + cos(Phi)*cos(Psi)*sin(The)) - A - B \\ 
 & V*(cos(Phi)*cos(Psi) + sin(Phi)*sin(Psi)*sin(The)) - C - D \\ 
 & W*cos(Phi)*cos(The) - U*sin(The)  
\end{cases}
```

But, I am not sure that this words will be okay, because I am not a native English user, so, I want to ask your advice.

Is "Let" and "than, full dynamic model is" the correct wording?

Could you give me some help?
Please, let me know!

[image]

Comment: It would help to use "operator names", i.e. `\cos`, `\log`, `\min`, etc. Really a capital (big) phi and psi? Use `\Psi` to typeset it. Typically, instead of `*`, a `\cdot` and even more typically, plain nothing is used. However, your question is not clear to me. Ok for whom?

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly you're trying to obtain. What are `The` and `conj`? Other than that, the usual functions  are defined as commands and therefore begin with a backslash (e.g. `\cos` or `\sin`). So do Greek letters in maths.

Comment: Thanks you guys ! and Thanks you for your time.
I am so sorry, my question was not clear( I will care more in next time) I wanted ask that "Let, than, full dynamic model is" is fine expression or not.

Comment: If you want to write math symbols, you should Oleg's advise. I'm guessing, but maybe you want a `\Theta` and about `conj`, is it a conjugate? Like `\bar` or `\overline`?. If would be helpful to include your intended result.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have edited my qeustion again with more clear meaning.

Comment: @유민재 "Then, the full dynamic model is...", if you mean that. TeX.SE is about TeX, not English grammar. People will be very rough with you if your questions are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks you, JairoADelRio. I will write my question more carefully in next time.

Comment: The last 3 lines make no sense mathematically. Should there be some equals signs?

Answer (score 1):

So, it did not fit the comment. From a pure TeX'y point of view, there are some adjustments to the typesetting, but I am unsure, what is your actual question.

- Small greek letters
- Proper operators with `\`
- Better alignment at split
- No parenthesis at trigonometric functions
- No multiplication sign, but some spacing
- Equation environment with numbering
- Full document
- Alignment still needs some work (play with `&`)

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &= V \cos\phi \; \sin\psi \\
B &= \cos\psi \; \sin\phi \sin\theta + U \cos\psi \; \cos\theta \\
C &= W \cos\psi \; \sin\phi \\
D &= \cos\phi \; \sin\psi \; \sin\theta + U \cos\theta \; \sin\psi
\end{split}
\end{equation}
than, full dynamic model is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  P x =& R V - Q W + g \sin\theta \\ 
  Q x =& P W - R U - g \cos\overline{\theta} \; \sin\phi \\ 
  R x =& Q U - P V + \frac{Fb}{m} - g \cos\phi \; \cos\theta \\ 
&W \sin\phi \; sin\psi + \cos\phi \; cos\psi \; \sin\theta - A - B \\ 
&V \cos\phi \;\ cos\psi + \sin\phi \; \sin\psi \; \sin\theta - C - D \\ 
&W cos\phi \;\ cos\theta - U sin\theta  
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I appreciate for your time. and I am sorry that I didn't make clear question, and I will care it in next time. my question was about English expression. But, your answer gave to me big help.

Let and than, full dynamic model is will be okay ?

Comment: again, Thanks you for your help deeply.

Comment: English language is out of scope of this site, but it looks ok – with an exception, you want "then", an implication, not a comparison. If it is for a paper, there are (payed) language services out there, your journal would recommend some of them quite uninvitedly. Those seem to do a great job.

Comment: Thanks you, Oleg Lobachev, yes it is my mistake. I will carefully thinking in next time before ask the question.

Comment: you missed a few `\ ` for some of the sin and cos terms...

Comment: @oliversm Yeah, I noticed too. Feel free to edit.